# fail to add Base64 in JSON object

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create the `JSON` containing the image in Base64 format.
Sample JSON:

```
{ "name":"NameOfPerson","profile_pic":"base64String"}
```

The scenario is: I want to store this JSONObject to MySQL database under blob field. But I failed to create the JSON on android its because of the length of base64String.

Now I'm looking for the solution. All the solutions and alternative ways are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: ``But I failed to create the JSON`` why? what's the error or problem?

Comment: @mmuzahid because of the length of base64String. (already mentioned)

Comment: what kind of Error your are getting?

Comment: And how long is the string? (How are you getting the string from the image, too... what image format are you using, with what options?) There's a lot of context missing here.

Comment: You could store the images url in database and store only path in JSON. Converting image to base64 or bitmap could be done in android. If you want it to be done this way, then i could most code for you.

Comment: Why cannot you use HTTPClient to upload your image?

Comment: @Sibidharan You are true, but I want above structure to be stored to database.

Comment: @iSandeep This is not a good practice! Now just try to resize and compress the image, then convert it into Base64. You are using it in Android or Standalone JAVA application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you are not compressing the image because base64 encoded data un-compressed image is too large and this complete encoded data can't be sent. In one case, it may be sent but in general, string is too large. Compress the bitmap before encode. Compressing to 70% will do the work for you

Comment: "Compressing to 70% will do the work for you" - how can you know that? We have no idea how large the original image is.

Comment: I have used this compression rate. How much the large image is, compress 70 % and saving in JPEG did the work

Comment: Right, so it happened to work *in your specific case*. You can't generalize from that to a situation we don't know much about.

Comment: No, that's not the case. 70% Jpeg compression brings the encoded string to an accepted json data string.

Comment: @Mustansar Saeed I just tried as you said, `ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();` but its not working

Comment: What's the issue? you have entered `100` which means do not compress. and secondly, you can use `JPEG` format with `70`

Comment: @MustansarSaeed: What do you believe to be the limit of the JSON string here? Do you believe that 70% compression will meet that limit for, say, an input image of 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 pixels, with a high level of incompressible detail?

Comment: @Mustansar Saeed, Thanks it works for me but still this is unclear why 70%, can you please elaborate it!

Comment: You have to set the threshold. You can set to 80% as well or 60 %. As Images can be larger so 70% brings the image to acceptable state. This is my opinion

Comment: @MustansarSaeed ok, Thanks for the help.

Comment: "As Images can be larger so 70% brings the image to acceptable state." Again, without knowing the original image size or the final size requirements, I don't see how you can say that.

Comment: What do you recommend, how this should be tackled?

Comment: I would - and have - recommend that the OP provides more detailed requirements.